# How can I change the status bar background, like in the twitter app?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

Many apps, like twitter, change the background color of the navigation bar and also the status bar, making them an integrated piece of design.

Here is an example screenshot:
[image]

I'm looking for a way to create that effect, changing both bars colors. Specially the status bar.

How could I achieve it?

Comment: Light and Default set the color of the text in status bar to either black or white. The status bar itself is transparent so it will simply have any color that is beneath it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways in which I found to do that.

**First one**

Through xcode, if you've added the Bar manually to your viewController.

It is under the "Bar Tint" option

See this image: http://picpaste.com/f4e9ba0f2e78b88b227e95d61e55c539.png

**Second one**

Programmatically, if you have a Navigation Controller.

For that method to work you need to put the code on the viewDidLoad() on the Navigation Controller itself.

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myBarColor = UIColor(red: 64/256, green: 86/256, blue: 106/256, alpha: 1.0)

        self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = myBarColor

    }

}
```

**Edit: Addressing the status bar**

```
let myBarColor = UIColor(red: 64/256, green: 86/256, blue: 106/256, alpha: 1.0)

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
    view.backgroundColor = myBarColor

    self.view.addSubview(view)
```

**Quick explanation of the values in UIColor() constructor**

The UIColor() Constructor I used uses RGB values in the Red: Green: Blue: parameters in a range from 0.0 to 1.0. To convert the hexadecimal value to RGB in a simple a way, you could open the color picker in XCode, paste in your hexadecimal value and then put down the Red Green and Blue values on those parameters, each divided by 256 to conform to the 0.0 to 1.0 scale. The values I've put in will match the colors you've requested in the comments. The last parameter is the alpha value, which you can use from 0 to 1.0.

Comment: OP asks about status bar, not navigation bar.

Comment: Missed that. I need to learn how to read, I think. Will ammend the answer. I did that with a hack using addSubview

Comment: @Losiowaty fixed it, mate. Sorry for the oversight.

Comment: I can't seem to get the color value I want, Im trying to get to get the hexadecimal color code #40566A instead of the purple, what would that be ? Im confused as to how you did 0.5, 0.2 and 0.5. I would normally go with 0x40, 0x56, 0x6A but that does not work.

Comment: Other than that, it works fine so thanks, I just can't figure out how to put my own color in there.

Comment: @TrentonTyler , I'm going to amend the answer with the right color for your hexadecimal.

Comment: Awesome thank you :)

Comment: Check the answer, the color is in there now with a little explanation of a way to convert your colors in the future.